# Is there a way to combine (JOIN) data from 2 tables together with SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I tried a few things to combine 2 tables, but the results returns only the data from the first table.

This are my tables:

```
 [Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}

 [Table("Company")]
public class Company
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my query:

```
 var result = await _Connection.QueryAsync<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person JOIN Company ON Person.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID");

        return result;
```

But it only gives the properties from the first table "Person". What did i forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use Present tense after did ;)

But actually this -  `_Connection.QueryAsync<Person>` will return only Person fields because you specified a concrete Person type as a generic.

Create a 3rd class which has both Person and Company fields or use an anonymous type, then use something like this:

```
var query = from person in await db.Table<Person>().ToListAsync()
    join company in await db.Table<Company>().ToListAsync()
    on person.CompanyID = company.CompanyID
    select new 
    {
        Name = person.Name,
        CompanyName = company.Name
        // And so on
    }
```

Note: this will load all records to the memory because of ToListAsync()

**Update:**
Instead of anonynous type, you can change your `select` to this:

```
PersonCompany personCompany = from person in .....
//---cut
on person.CompanyID = company.CompanyID
        select new PersonCompany
        {
            Name = person.Name,
            CompanyName = company.Name
            // And so on
    }
```

Comment: A 3rd class? Do I need to copy data into it or just use it like this then: var result = await _Dataconnection.QueryAsync<PersonCompany>....?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, yes, this class is only for data storage. So unlike anonymous type you can pass it somewhere or return it from your repository method. Answer updated